# Majuscule au « nous » de majesté ?

Tags: typographie, pronoms-personnels, majuscules, vouvoiement

Doit-on ou non mettre une majuscule au *nous* de majesté ?

Comme dans l’exemple :

> Sachez que *Nous*, empereur des Qin, exigeons votre soumission.

L’[article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_des_majuscules_en_fran%C3%A7ais) pourtant fort détaillé de Wikipédia sur le sujet, ne semble pas en faire mention.

Dans [*De l’horrible danger de la lecture*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/De_l%u2019horrible_danger_de_la_lecture) de Voltaire où le personnage fictif de Jusuf Chéribi se… noussoie, il ne semble pas faire usage de majuscule « […] a rapporté parmi *n*ous le pernicieux usage de l’imprimerie […] ».

En fin de compte, qu’en est-il ? Qu’en dit le *Lexique des règles typographiques* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non, les pronoms, de majesté ou pas, ne prennent pas de majuscule en français sauf bien sûr quand ils sont placés au début d'une phrase.

La seule entorse à cette règle concerne les pronoms qui font référence à Dieu qui peuvent prendre une majuscule dans les textes religieux monothéistes, mais sans que ce soit une obligation.

Comme l'a indiqué Pas un Clue en commentaire, on peux parfois trouver des majuscules aux pronoms qui se réfèrent à des personnes de rang très élevé comme dans cet exemple :

> *Je prie **Votre** Altesse Royale de me permettre de **Lui** écrire une fois encore. Si **Elle** pense que j'ai déjà trop abusé de **Sa** bienveillance, **Elle** n'aura qu'à laisser cette lettre sans réponse* Bernanos dans une lettre à la comtesse de Paris, 1939.

Comment: Je verrais très bien, pour insister sur l'égocentrisme, la confiance énorme ou la puissance redoutable d'un monarque, empereur ou autre type de tyran ou dictateur, que l'on utilise une majuscule au pronom le désignant (celui-ci fût-il à la première, à la deuxième ou à la troisième personne, singulier ou pluriel selon le cas), ce qui placerait alors son pouvaoir à un niveau approchant celui d'un dieu. Une telle autorité demeure possible, tout au moins dans la fiction, mais probablement aussi dans une certaine mesure dans notre monde...

Comment: Je croirais même me rappeler que parfois, dans un roman, le pronom désignant un certain personnage *(père, chef de tribu, roi/reine, dieu/déesse, ancêtre décédé, etc.)* est systématiquement affublé d'une majuscule, exprimant de ce fait par un non-dit éloquent le pouvoir qui lui est attribué, pouvoir inspirant parfois la déférence, parfois la crainte ou la révolte, mais toujours une bonne dose de respect.

Comment: Aurais-tu des sources @Montéedelait, je te prie ? Après, ça me parait excessif, mais je demeure intéressé.

Comment: @Fauve Il n'est guère facile de retrouver des exemples dans la grande quantité de romans que j'ai lus, alors je me rabats sur *Le Bon usage*, qui en contient certains, dont celui-ci (14e édition, §101-a-3), qui illustre convenablement mon propos: *«Je prie Votre Altesse Royale de me permettre de Lui écrire une fois encore. Si Elle pense que j'ai déjà trop abusé de Sa bienveillance, Elle n'aura qu'à laisser cette lettre sans réponse»* (Bernanos dans une lettre à la comtesse de Paris, 1939)

Comment: Je connais cet usage. On y fait recourt lorsque l’on s’adresse à une personne royale ou de rang très élevé. Mais en revanche, il ne semblerait pas que l’on agisse de même lorsque c’est cette personne même qui parles d’elle même. « — Je dis que *V*otre altesse ne saurait être plus juste envers nous. — C’est que *n*otre bienveillance est sans borne. ».